# Derivative of trace involving inverse and Hadamard product

Tags: inverse, matrix-calculus, trace, hadamard-product

Let $A, B$ be symmetric $(n \times n)$ matrices and let $A$ be invertible. I am looking for the derivative
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial A} \operatorname{tr}[A^{-1}(A \odot B)], $$
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product. I guess the result is something like
$$ -A^{-2}(A \odot B) + A^{-1}(I \odot B), $$
where $I$ is the $(n \times n)$ identity matrix, but that's not quite correct. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use a colon (:) to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Write the function in  terms of this product. Then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A^{-1}:B\odot A \cr\cr
d\phi &= A^{-1}:B\odot dA + B\odot A:dA^{-1} \cr
 &= B\odot A^{-1}:dA - B\odot A:A^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1} \cr
 &= (B\odot A^{-1} - A^{-1}(B\odot A)A^{-1}):dA \cr\cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A} &= B\odot A^{-1} - A^{-1}(B\odot A)A^{-1} \cr
}$$
It helps to know a few rules for manipulating Frobenius/Hadamard products
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= B:A \cr
 A\odot B &= B\odot A \cr
 A:(B\odot C) &= (A\odot B):C\cr
}$$